# Manifest.json Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url

Tags: json, google-chrome, web, manifest, lighthouse

i have problem with the **start_url** And i dont know why is this code wrong i searching on all forums and internet but i cant found the answer for this, the **Lighthouse** say this:

Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url
The service worker is the technology that enables your app to use many Progressive Web App features, such as offline, add to homescreen, and push notifications. Learn more.

and if i add on the `manifest.json` add `start_url:` still dont works i found only one answer is use `scope:` but is still dont works.

[image: Manifest.json]

```json
{
  "name": "Heexy",
  "short_name": "Heexy",
  "description": "Heexy is the private and fast search engine without ads!.",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "start_url":"/?start=url",
  "scope": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#03adfc",
  "background_color": "white",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://cdn.heexy.org/images/logo.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add service-worker.js script